# Cookie not being created and stored websphere

Tags: session, cookies, websphere

I've a WEB project deployed in WAS 6.1 server which creates and stores a cookie for session management. I've upgraded WAS to v7.0.0.27 and now the cookie is not being stored nor created. I'm using jdk1.6_19, WEB Module 2.5 and EJB 3.0.

This is the way I create the cookie:

```
    Cookie cookie = new Cookie(user, divison);
    cookie.setMaxAge(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    cookie.setPath("/");
    res.addCookie( cookie );
```

I've spent 2 weeks on this but nothing seems to be working.
I've patched my RSA to have 7.5.5.5.001 Fix, I've gone thru Websphere console for setting cookies, I've deployed the same application in Tomcat and the cookie is getting created but in WAS Websphere v7.0.0.27 I can't make it.

Any idea or solution for this issue will be appreciated

Comment: You do not see any exceptions? Has the output stream from the web module already been comitted when you try to add the cookie?

Comment: nope any exception is being sent to the console. yes the output stream stream is commited

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is from last year, but I had trouble with this for the last few days and found an answer:

Websphere 7 has another date format for the expire date (YY instead of YYYY).
For details, please have a look at this [Ticket](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM34869).

Hope I was able to help.